# On-premise Active directory login using LDAP and SSO

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, on-premises-instances

We are developing a ReactJs and NodeJs application where node has to authenticate AD users using LDAP.

We are able to complete the authentication successfully using LDAP,

But the requirement is, in On-prem users are already logged in to the AD and if they open our web it should login without asking credentials again, it it is not happening with LDAP integration.

Can some one please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add SSO in on-prem Active directory login using LDAP, please follow below steps:

***Go to Administration -> Applications and enable Single Sign-On -> click setting -> select LDAP method.***

If you want your users to login without using credentials again, set the option to use only SSO authentication only.

***UseResponse internal account is created, when a new user logs in against the LDAP server. If you don't want to send internal registration credentials, Disable Registration Email.***

In addition to these, include basic settings of your connection:

- Give hostname or IP of your LDAP server
- Add ldaps:// to hostname when the server has secure connection
- Give Base Distinguished Name for your AD with default value dc=localhost.
- Enter administration credentials for the connection, if your LDAP server requires authentication.

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Using LDAP as a Single Sign-On (Active Directory) | Integrations | Help Center - UseResponse](https://help.useresponse.com/knowledge-base/article/using-ldap-as-a-single-sign-on).